# Filling-in missing data and merge with main set

Tags: python, pandas

For a dataset DF, I would like to add temperatures taken from a secondary dataset TEMP. 
TEMP does not have all dates. Missing dates need to be interpolated in such a way that the latest available value is filled-in for missing values. For ex. if temperature is missing for 2019-2-20, but it was available for 2019-2-19, it will fill-in this value. This can be done by using `pd.DataFrame(x.asfreq('D')).ffill().reset_index(drop=False)`.

When there are multiple temperature measures per day, a weighted average should be applied.
In the current code, dates are pre-selected using `isin` to limit datasize.

The code works, but is not optimal if data become big, paticularly if temperature data from 1000s of places and dates need to be filled-in and merged to DF. I am searching for a better solution regarding timing / memory, for ex. based on itertools, apply, generator expression, or anything else.

Below I show a fictive small reproducible example with code.

**Modules:**

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
```

**Fictive data:**

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-13', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-22', '2019-02-14'], 'place':['A', 'A','A','A','B','C']})
TEMP = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2019-01-10', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-20', '2019-01-20', '2019-01-22', '2019-01-23', '2019-01-24', '2019-02-14', '2019-02-14'], 'place':['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'], 'temp': [5, 7, 9, 10, 10, 2, 0, 10, 11], 'quantity': [3,5,2,1,1,2,2,1,3]})
DF['date'] = pd.to_datetime(DF['date'])
TEMP['date'] = pd.to_datetime(TEMP['date'])
```

**The code:**

```
if 'temp' in DF.columns: 
    del DF['temp']
else: print('No variable temp found in DF')


def filltemps(dat1, dat2):
    """dat1: TEMP
    dat2: DF"""

    global totmp
    places = dat2['place'].unique()
    mx=len(places)
    totmp = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'temp', 'place'])

    for i in range(mx):
        mp=[]
        dd1=[]
        nsp = pd.DataFrame(dat1[ (dat1['place']==places[i]) ])
        nsp = nsp[['date', 'quantity', 'temp']]
        prod = lambda w,z: w*z
        nsp['sumn'] = prod(nsp['temp'], nsp['quantity'])
        wavg = lambda y,x: y/x
        c3 = wavg(nsp.groupby('date')['sumn'].agg('sum'), nsp.groupby('date')['quantity'].agg('sum'))
        mp = pd.DataFrame(c3.asfreq('D')).ffill().reset_index(drop=False)
        mp.columns = ['date', 'temp']
        mp['place'] = np.array([places[i]] * len(mp))
        mp['date'] = pd.to_datetime(mp['date'])
        dd1 = dat2.loc[dat2['place']==places[i], ['date']]
        mp = mp[ mp['date'].isin(list(pd.to_datetime(dd1['date']))) ]
        totmp = pd.concat([totmp, mp])
    return totmp
```

Timing by `%timeit TEMP2 = filltemps(TEMP, DF)` shows 116 ms ± 401 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In TEMP2, it can be seen that as expected a weighted average was computed for place C:

```
TEMP2 = filltemps(TEMP, DF)
```

TEMP2 will be merged with the original DF. Note that there can be missing values if no earlier data were available.

```
DF = pd.merge(DF, TEMP2, how='left', on=['date', 'place'])
```

DF, the expected outcome, should look like this:

[image]

Your pointers and help are very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calculate weighted average in TEMP. Fill missing dates in TEMP by place and merge the resulting dataframe with DF.

```
TEMP.date = pd.to_datetime(TEMP.date) 

TEMP = TEMP.groupby(['date', 'place']).apply(lambda x: np.round(np.average(x['temp'],weights=x['quantity']), 2)).reset_index(name = 'temp')

DF.merge(TEMP.set_index('date').groupby('place')['temp'].apply(lambda x: x.asfreq('D', method='ffill')).reset_index(), 'left')

    date        place   temp
0   2019-01-01  A       NaN
1   2019-01-11  A       5.00
2   2019-01-13  A       5.00
3   2019-01-14  A       7.00
4   2019-01-22  B       10.00
5   2019-02-14  C       10.75
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a replacement for `filltemps` that works 10x faster on my machine. It also uses `apply`, as requested :)

```py
def interpolate_temps(temp_data, other_data):
    """ Interpolate temperature by place and location on a daily frequency.

    Parameters
    ----------
    temp_data : pd.DataFrame
        with columns:
            date : datetime
            place : categorical
            temp : numerical
            quantity : numerical

    other_Data : pd.DataFrame
        with columns:
            date : datetime
            place : categorical

    Returns
    -------
    pd.DataFrame
        With date and place in the index and a temp column
    """
    def weighted_average(df, col1, col2):
        """Average of col1 weighted by col2"""
        return (df[col1] * df[col2]).sum() / df[col2].sum()

    results = []
    for place in temp_data.place.unique():
        dates_needed = other_data[other_data.place == place].date.unique()
        result = (temp_data[temp_data.place==place]
                  .groupby('date')
                  .apply(weighted_average, 'temp', 'quantity')
                  .reindex(dates_needed, method='ffill')
                  .to_frame('temp')
                  .assign(place=place)
                  .set_index('place', append=True)
                 )
        results.append(result)
    return pd.concat(results)
```

It follows the same basic structure as yours:

1. Iterate through each place.

   1. Take the weighted average of temperature by dates.
   2. Fill in the missing values with `ffill`.
   3. Add place back in as a column.
2. Join the results for each place

The major advance in time is downselecting to the dates needed for a particular place before running `ffill`. This should also make it more memory-efficient, as should the fact that we're not making so many named intermediate objects. The biggest place where this was an issue in your code was `totmp = pd.concat([totmp, mp])`, where you created `len(place)` different versions of `totmp`, whereas in `interpolate_temps` we wait until the end to `pd.concat(results)` all at once.

The result of `interpolate_temps` has `date` and `place` in the index, so you can join it like this:

```py
DF.join(interpolate_temps(TEMP, DF), on=['date', 'place'])
```

or reset the index and merge like you had been doing.

The only other advice I have is to use more verbose variable names. I never really figured out what many of them meant, and that made it harder to understand your code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similay to the one ob Vaishali but I want to point out one pitfall of `asfreq`.

Let's start at the beginning. We calculate the weighted averages:

```
TEMP.groupby(['date', 'place']).apply(lambda x: np.round(np.average(x['temp'],weights=x['quantity']), 2)).reset_index(name = 'temp')
```

Now we calculate the full date range:

```
rng = pd.date_range(DF.date.min(), DF.date.max(), freq='D')
```

We use this data range to reindex the temperatures:

```
TEMP = TEMP.groupby('place')['date', 'temp'].apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').reindex(rng).ffill()).reset_index().rename(columns={'level_1': 'date'})
```

In contrast to `as_freq` we will now also handle the case that the temperature time series is "shorter" then the location series.

Finally we can put everything together:

```
DF.merge(TEMP, on=['date', 'place'])
```

If we sligthly modify the input by changing the last date:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2019-01-01', '2019-01-11', '2019-01-13', '2019-01-14', '2019-01-22', '2019-02-15'], 'place':['A', 'A','A','A','B','C']})
```

the solution of Ruthger delivers:

```
        date place  temp
1 2019-01-11     A   5.0
3 2019-01-13     A   5.0
4 2019-01-14     A   7.0
0 2019-01-22     B  10.0
```

Vaishali:

```
        date place  temp
0 2019-01-01     A   NaN
1 2019-01-11     A   5.0
2 2019-01-13     A   5.0
3 2019-01-14     A   7.0
4 2019-01-22     B  10.0
5 2019-02-15     C   NaN
```

Joerg:

```
0 2019-01-01     A    NaN
1 2019-01-11     A   5.00
2 2019-01-13     A   5.00
3 2019-01-14     A   7.00
4 2019-01-22     B  10.00
5 2019-02-15     C  10.75
```

Briefly the terms:

```
%timeit Ruthger(TEMP, DF)
526 ms ± 36.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit Vaishali(TEMP, DF)
12.1 ms ± 135 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit Joerg(TEMP, DF)
14.9 ms ± 872 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```